# Proof by induction that sum of terms $a_i$ with $a_i = b + i \cdot c$ is $(n+1) \frac{a_0 + a_n}{2}$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, arithmetic-progressions

So I have this problem:

> Let the finite sequence $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be defined by $a_i = b + i\cdot c$. Prove by induction on $n$ that the sum of the terms in the sequence is $\displaystyle(n+1)\frac{a_0 + a_n}{2}$. (Hint: in the base case, $n = 0$ and so $a_0$ is equal to $a_n$. For the induction case, note that the sum for $n+1$ is equal to the sum for $n$ plus the one new term $a_{n+1}$)

So for the base case I have that $a_0$ is equal to $b$ and so $a_n$ is also equal to $b$. When I plug that into the equation $\displaystyle(n+1)\frac{a_0 + a_n}{2}$ I get $b = b$ which is true.

I am stuck on the induction part. Here is am using the hint and saying that $s(n+1) = \displaystyle(n+1)\frac{a_0 + a_n}{2} + a_{n+1}$

Is this step right? Or do i also have to plug $n+1$ int the first $n$ of the equation? Where do I go from there?

Comment: Convert $a_n$ to $b+nc$, and the equivalent for $a_{n+1}$.  Expand and simplify.

Comment: ok, but I am correct in adding the a<sub>n+1</sub> to the end of the S(n+1) equation? if so, does that convert to b+(n+1)c? and then just go from there?

Answer (score 1):

For the induction step, you say “Suppose the sum of $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n$ is  $(n+1)\frac{a_0+a_n}{2}$. Then I need t0 show that the sum of $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n, \color{red}{a_{n+1}}$ is $ (\color{red}{n+2})\frac{a_0+\color{red}{a_{n+1}}}{2}$.”

So you are allowed to *suppose* the first part, that the sum of $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n$ is  $(n+1)\frac{a_0+a_n}{2}$, and *use* that to show the second part, that the sum of $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n, \color{red}{a_{n+1}}$ is $ (\color{red}{n+2})\frac{a_0+\color{red}{a_{n+1}}}{2}$.  If you can do that, you win.

Now you know that the sum of  $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n, \color{red}{a_{n+1}}$ must be the same as the sum of  $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n$, plus $\color{red}{a_{n+1}}$.  And you know from the "suppose" part that the sum of $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n$ is  $(n+1)\frac{a_0+a_n}{2}$.  So that means that the sum of  $a_0, a_1,\ldots a_n, \color{red}{a_{n+1}}$ must be $(n+1)\frac{a_0+a_n}{2} + \color{red}{a_{n+1}}$.

Can you show that this last expression is equal to $ (\color{red}{n+2})\frac{a_0+\color{red}{a_{n+1}}}{2}$?  If so, you win.  You'll need to use the fact that $a_i = b + i\cdot c$.

Comment: So if I substitute, b+ic I get: (n+1)(( b + (b + nc))/2) + 2(b+(n+1)c)/2 .... I am stuck from here. I have tried various different ways to try and get what I need but cannot @MJD

Comment: Love the color...

Comment: @john Why are you stuck? Is the problem that you don't know how to combine the fractions?

Comment: @MJD I can combine them, but when I do so I do not get what it is supposed to be. Or at least the way I have been trying to combine them and rearrange the variables is not giving me the answer I am looking for. It may be obvious but I am having trouble seeing it.

Comment: This is no longer a problem with induction, but a problem with simple algebra.  I suggest that you post a new question about just the algebra that you are having trouble with.  (I also suggest that you start with two clean sheets of paper, one for each of the two expressions, and on each sheet, in large, clear symbols, simplify each expression as far as you can.)